# How to clear the text fields in fragments on back pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am facing the issue of clearing the text view on back pressed in the fragment. When I set the text to textview in Fragment A and then clicked submit button to move the next fragment B. After that when i back pressed in Fragment B to go back to the previous fragment B. In that Fragment A the textview text is not cleared how to clear the text in textview. Please help me how to solve this.

The below code is for replacing the fragment from Fragment A to B.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("fromDate",fromDate);
args.putString("toDate",toDate);
args.putInt("account",accountPosition);
//     ldf.setArguments(args);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ldf).commit();
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(Fragment_Retailer_Home_Main.class.getSimpleName(),
FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);


Fragment_Retailer_account_Statements fragment = new  Fragment_Retailer_account_Statements();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragment.setArguments(args);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,"Fragment_Retailer_account_Statement");
//         fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Fragment_Retail_Enter_Date.class.getSimpleName() );
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: have you tried getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, ldf).commit();

Comment: just clear the text on onPause() callback while moving from one screen to another

Answer (score 2):

use `onResume()` method

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    /*code to set text to null 
      eg : txtBoxName.setText(""); or
           txtBoxName.clearComposingText(); */

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fragment A:**

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frag, Fragment B)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

**From Fragment B(back press) :**

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider not adding the fragment to backStack, and recreating a new one on back pressed.
You can add a flag to your activity, and check the flag inside OnResume in Fragment you would like to get cleared.

Comment: There is multiple fragments in my project .How can I implement your methods